# Sorting and storing data in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have some issue in `UITableView`. I want to show artist name, number of songs and artist images in cell and artist id. that values come from web services.

Number of section in table is equal to number of alphabet.

Each section sort by alphabet by artistName.

I sort the section. But issue in displaying Images and Number of songs corresponding artist name.

The code is here:

```
 for (int i=0; i<[arrayFromWebServiceParse count]; i++)
    {  
        [artistArray addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"ArtistName="]];
        [ImgArray addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"Image="]];
        [SongArray addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"Songs="]];
        [ArtistIdArray addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"AID="]];
    }
```

`arrayFromWebServiceParse` after parsing.

Answer (score 1):

instead of making three array make a single `NSMutableArray` like this

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrayFromWebServiceParse count]; i++)
{ 
    NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [tempArr addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"ArtistName="]];
    [tempArr addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"Image="]];
    [tempArr addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"Songs="]];
    [tempArr addObject:[[arrayFromWebServiceParse objectAtIndex:i ]objectForKey:@"AID="]];
    [artistArray addObject:tempArr];
}
```

Comment: your welcome and please accept my answer and vote me so that any other user can also know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having these items in different arrays, you make an `NSDictionary` object with the 3 items and add it to an array. Otherwise you can have a custom class with the three members and add the list of the objects to the array.